# error string variable in delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

Hi I have the following code

```
delete: = 'testing # {}' testing ';
```

the problem is that when I use 'fails because it does not know how to avoid this error in other languages ​​such as perl is solved by using \' delphi but does not work.

someone could help form the variable without errors?

Comment: You did not provide any information about what you are attempting to do, or what the error message is saying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Assuming** that your problem is trying to put a quote character inside a string literal, then try this:

```
delete := 'testing # {}'' testing ';
```